# Dimension of an eigenspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The minimum dimension of an eigenspace is 0, now lets assume we have a nxn matrix A such that
rank(A-$\lambda$I) = n

rank(A-$\lambda$I) = n $\implies$ no free variables
Now the null space is the space in which a matrix is 0, so in this case

nul(A-$\lambda$I) = {0}

and isn't the eigenspace just the kernel of the above matrix? Which would imply that the eigenspace is 0 dimensional.

Yet it says that the minimum dimension an eigenspace can be is 1 dimensional, aka a line, so our solution set should be a line for the above matrix?

Could someone explain where I'm going wrong with this thinking.

Comment: The nullspace of $A - \lambda I$ is called an "eigenspace" only when $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, i.e., only when the nullity of $A - \lambda I$ is larger than $0$.  So by definition, there is no such thing as a zero-dimensional "eigenspace."  If $A - \lambda I$ has rank $n$, you correctly observe that the nullspace of $A - \lambda I$ will be $\{0\}$, and both of these conditions tell you that $\lambda$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$.  As for what this means for "our solution set" - this is unclear. "Solution set" to what equation?

Comment: Oh my god right, sorry I got confused I forgot that in the equation (A-$\lambda$I)*x, x would be correspondent to the eigenvector it would be multiplied with and since there are no free variables $\implies$ the only solution for x is the vector 0 which is not considered an eigenvector as any scalar * 0 leads to 0, so $\implies$ $\lambda$ is not an eigenvalue, thank you so much for clearing this up! @leslietownes